# How to advice-add a function with no arguments to a function that takes arguments?

Tags: elisp

Say I have a functions as follows:

```lisp
  (defun my/test-a (n)
    (interactive)
    (message n))
    
  (defun my/test-b ()
    (interactive)
    (sleep-for .5)
    (message "Message - B.")
    (sleep-for .5))
```

I then advice my/test-a with mytest-b like so: `(advice-add 'my/test-a :after #'my/test-b)`.

However when I call `(my/test-a "Message - A.")` I get a "Wrong number of arguments" error. My understanding is that add-advice is feeding the argument into my/test-b, which is not expecting any arguments.

How to advice-add a function with no arguments to a function that takes arguments?

I could change my/test-b so it takes an argument and doesn't use it, but that feels very messy.

Related followup - how could I advise `find-file` with a function with no arguments (like `my/test-b`)? I understand find-file is an unusual case, because it doesn't need an argument if called interactively. But if I run `(advice-add 'find-file :after #'my/test-b)` and then `(call-interactively 'find-file)` I get a "Wrong Number Of Arguments" error again.

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

Your advice function has to accept the arguments for the original function.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Advice Combinators` says:

> `:after`
> Call FUNCTION after the old function.  **Both functions receive the
> same arguments**, and the return value of the composition is the
> return value of the old function.  More specifically, the
> composition of the two functions behaves like:
> `(lambda (&rest r) (prog1 (apply OLDFUN r) (apply FUNCTION r)))`

A way to take arbitrary arguments and ignore them is:

```
(defun foo (&rest _args) ...)
```

The underscore tells the byte-compiler that the arguments are unused in the function body on purpose.